# `get` that returns None is read as string mypy?

Tags: python, mypy

Im getting a weird error when I pass a `.get` for a nonexistent key (ie the the `.get` returns None) into a function that has the typing `Optional[List[str]]`:

```
incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "Optional[List[str]]"
```

This results from an operation that looks like this:

```
def test(a: Optional[List[str]]) -> None:
    pass


my_dict = {'k':'v'}
test(my_dict.get('foo'))
```

Not sure why the `.get` would be interpreted by mypy as `Optional[str]`?

Comment: Your dictionary contains strings as values. `test()` expects a list as the parameter.

Comment: @Barmar ya, but cant i just as easily have a dictionary `{'k':'v', 'foo':[1,2,3]}?

Comment: `get()` returns a value from the dictionary or `None` if the value isn't found. Since the dictionary values are all strings, the type of `.get()` is `Optional[str]`

Comment: You could, but mypy sees the dictionary that you're using, so it infers the type from that.

Comment: "Not sure why the .get would be interpreted by mypy as Optional[str]?" Because the check is based only on data types, not based on trying to run the code ahead of time. `.get`, by definition, is supposed to return `None` when the key is not found; so if it is determined to return `str` when the key is found, then the inferred return type is "either a `str` instance or `None`" which is what `Optional[str]` means.

Comment: If you didn't assign the dictionary as a literal value, mypy wouldn't know what the type is, and it wouldn't complain.

Comment: "but cant i just as easily have a dictionary `{'k':'v', 'foo':[1,2,3]}" Yes, and *if you had* that dictionary, Mypy would infer a different return type. In either case, this happens because *the types* of the data can be inferred ahead of time, because all the data is visible; but the calculations are not actually attempted ahead of time. If Mypy doesn't see the literal initialization of the dict, then it can't reason like that at all.

Comment: If you want to understand generally how this works, you should start by *reading the documentation* for Mypy.

Comment: Seems odd.. but i guess ill just do with that.. Thanks!

Comment: A mixed-type dict like `{'k':'v', 'foo':[1,2,3]}` will also cause mypy to object to `test(my_dict['foo'])`, since the best it can do guessing the value type of the dictionary is `object`. For a dict lookup to match the type, *all* the values must be lists of strings (or `None`, I guess).

Comment: Good question because there are similar cases the comments help elucidate. I have a literal `dict` with `str` keys and I'm trying to `get` using a `str | None` key. I don't care if the key is `None`, the `dict.get` will just return `None` if the key isn't present. The key doesn't have to be `None` to not be present, any `str` lookup could also be a miss and return `None` but `mypy` is so strict that it can't tolerate `dict.get(None)` returning `None` even though it's obvious that we might get a `dict.get(str)` returning `None`. This is what `get` is for, but not in `mypy` world.